# Graphics from arrays in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I have attached a picture of what I have tried.

Starting from an array with values to graph and another array with the names of these values, I would want to graph them all. For later, from the front panel, I want to be able to choose which ones I want to visualize and which not. In the attached image is what I have tried and it does not work only know how to graph the 1 value with the first name but not the others.

[image: Attempt at graphing]

Answer (score 2):

The property you need for setting the names is "Active Plot". 
The key to writing multiple plots is the "Bundle" node (or "Bundle By Name").

[image: block diagram code]

Result:

[image: front panel image of Waveform Chart with multiple plots]

Comment: Hi,
at the end i found another solution and i have a well explained example. Do you know how to upload VI's here or I can't. Since, they helped me from the NI community.

Comment: There is no way to upload VIs here. You can create VI snippets (under the Edit menu) for a single VI diagram, which is a PNG that has embedded metadata that can reconstruct a VI, but this site often strips the metadata out. It is part of why there are so few LabVIEW questions on StackOverflow: our code doesn't display well here.